# Definition of Locus in Synthetic Geometry?

Tags: geometry, logic, formal-systems

How is "locus" defined in Euclidean geometry? I know that locus is defined as a set of all points satisfying a certain condition. But how do we define "locus" **within** an axiomatic system. The "points" and "lines" are primitive concepts and set theory is not buit into the system.

Comment: idk for sure, but probably it has to do with phrases of the sort "the curve traced by this point of this figure when you do this". See e.g. the standard definition of a tractrix.

Comment: I believe, some elements of set theory are used in Euclidean geometry axiomatic system like external prerequisites or something like this.

Comment: Locus is figure consisting of all points satisfying certain condition. Does such definition requires using set theory?

Comment: We can obviously define loci for models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your language, and let $\varphi(P)$ be a formula in the language, where $P$ is a variable point. Then, for each model $\mathfrak{A}$, the set $\{P \text{ is a point in } \mathfrak{A}: \varphi(P)\}$ is the locus of all points that satisfy $\varphi(P)$.

The formula $\varphi(P)$ is a syntactic object that represents the locus of all points $P$ with the property that $\varphi(P)$ is true.